# Minimal polynomial of $\operatorname{cd}\frac{4K}{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, definite-integrals, minimal-polynomials, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

Define
$$K=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$
and the Jacobi elliptic function $\operatorname{cd}$ with modulus $i$ by
$$\int_{\operatorname{cd}z}^1\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}=z$$
on $z\in [0,2K]$ and by
$$\operatorname{cd}(z+2K)=-\operatorname{cd}z$$
on the rest of the real line.

Then this function is $4K$-periodic and is an analog of the cosine function which is $2\pi$-periodic. Let $\operatorname{dmp}$ denote the ''degree of the minimal polynomial'' of an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then it is well-known that
$$\operatorname{dmp}\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{2n}}{4}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^\times$. (See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_of_2cos(2pi/n)).

This led me to the following conjecture:

> $$\operatorname{dmp}\operatorname{cd}\frac{4K}{n}\ge \frac{\sqrt{2n}}{4}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^\times$. Is this conjecture true or false? If this conjecture is true, then it has an application in an algorithm for evaluating elliptic integrals which I'm developing. This should provide an alternative to a known algorithm that is using elliptic curves. If the conjecture is false, can we come up with a simple non-trivial lower bound for $\operatorname{dmp}\operatorname{cd}\frac{4K}{n}$?

Example:
$$\operatorname{dmp}\operatorname{cd}\frac{4K}{5}=8$$
with the corresponding minimal polynomial
$$X^8-4X^7+4X^5-6X^4+4X^3-4X+1,$$
whereas
$$\frac{\sqrt{2\cdot 5}}{4}\approx 0.79$$
to two decimal places.

Comment: The tightest lower bound for $\varphi(n)$ is $(1-\varepsilon)e^{-\gamma}n/\log\log n$, so you technically can do much better.

Comment: As for your question, I highly doubt whether the number is algebraic at all

Comment: @TravorLZH It is algebraic, as you can verify by the addition law for elliptic functions.

Comment: @TravorLZH As for the bound: I need a **simple** non-trivial lower bound, say $\operatorname{dmp}\ge f(n)$, so that I can easily solve the inequality $d\ge f(n)$ for $n$.

Comment: Do the number fields generated by cd $\frac{4K}{n}$ always contain $2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{4n}\right)$, i.e. the totally real subfield of the $4n$ cyclotomic field?

Answer (score -1):

Some thoughts...

We have $cdz=sn(K-z).$ Using the addition formula of the [Jacobi's elliptic function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html) $sn$ and some $+K$ tricks I obtained the half-angle formula
$$cd(2z)=\frac{cd^4z+2cd^2z-1}{-cd^4z+2cd^2z+1}.$$
From this, I roughly observed that $$\text{dmp}\, cd\left(\frac{4K}{2^n}\right)\stackrel{?}{=}2^{2n-4}$$
for $n\geq2.$ Whereas, in trigonometric case, we have $\text{dmp}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^n}\right)=2^{n-2}.$ Therefore I would conjecture that
$$\text{dmp}\, cd\left(\frac{4K}{n}\right)\geq=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{4}\right)^2=\frac n8.$$

Comment: You made another conjecture, how is this supposed to be an answer? Please delete this.

Comment: Ok.... Your post.